# Optimize IF clause with block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something like:

```
<%= "<p class='...'>#{product.value}</p>".html_safe if product.value %>
```

So I want to show the `value` wrapped in some html if it exists. Problem is that `value` is a method that requires some calculations and the way above for every product value is calculated two times which doubles my page loading time.

Any way to optimize this?

Comment: If the logic is complex, consider moving this to a helper instead of doing it within your view. It'll make things much clearer! However, either of the two answers below would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```rb
<%= product.value.then { |v| content_tag(:p, v, class: '...') if v } %>
```

The `value` method is only called once on the `product` object. After that, it is passed to a block `then` that will define what is the result of the overall expression. Without calling again the `value` method, inside the block we determine what is the value that should be returned (if any).

**Note:** The generation of the HTML object has been replaced by an invocation of the [content_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) helper method.

Comment: In Rails you can also use `product.value.try { |v| ... }` because [`try`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) only yields if the receiver is not `nil`. (so you don't need an `if`)

Answer (score 4):

For readability reasons I would be very explicit:

```
<% if (calculated_value = product.value) %>
  <p class='...'><%= calculated_value %></p>
<& end %>
```